# Abort() error encountered when adding points from input PointCloud to OctreePointCloud in PCL

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I've encountered an error I'm having some difficulty solving in my current PCL c++ program. My original code is much larger and part of a classification project so I have tested using the following code and am still encountering my issue. When calling addPointsFromInputCloud() from my octree the function is running once for the first point, then appears to be unable to read the memory in which the defined input cloud is located. It throws the following error: R6010 - abort() has been called. I'm using PCL 1.8 with Visual Studio 2012. I have had PCL up and running in this project but started to have this issue yesterday after changing some binary reading code in an unrelated part of the project. In my header file I include:

```
    #include <pcl\point_types.h>
    #include <pcl\point_cloud.h>
    #include <pcl\octree\octree.h>
```

In my function in the corresponding class I attempt to implement the code from the basic PCL octree tutorial (http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/octree.php):

```
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

    // Generate pointcloud data
    cloud->width = 1000;
    cloud->height = 1;
    cloud->points.resize (cloud->width * cloud->height);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < cloud->points.size (); ++i) {
        cloud->points[i].x = 1024.0f * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
        cloud->points[i].y = 1024.0f * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
        cloud->points[i].z = 1024.0f * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
    }

    float resolution = 128.0f;

    pcl::octree::OctreePointCloudSearch<pcl::PointXYZ> octree (resolution);
    octree.setInputCloud(cloud);
    octree.addPointsFromInputCloud();
```

This throws the error above when attempting to execute the final line.

This is the code from octree_poointcloud.hpp wherein the failure occurs:

```
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    template<typename PointT, typename LeafContainerT, typename BranchContainerT, typename OctreeT> void
    pcl::octree::OctreePointCloud<PointT, LeafContainerT, BranchContainerT, OctreeT>::addPointsFromInputCloud ()
    {
      size_t i;

      if (indices_)
      {
        for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator current = indices_->begin (); current != indices_->end (); ++current)
        {
          assert( (*current>=0) && (*current < static_cast<int> (input_->points.size ())));

          if (isFinite (input_->points[*current]))
          {
            // add points to octree
            this->addPointIdx (*current);
          }
        }
      }
      else
      {
        for (i = 0; i < input_->points.size (); i++)
        {
          if (isFinite (input_->points[i]))
          {
            // add points to octree
            this->addPointIdx (static_cast<unsigned int> (i));
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The first execution of the loop under the else statement is successful but it then appears to be unable to read from _input and errors.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question and figured I'd let everyone know what my issue was. In the reading section of my program I had altered the packing to ensure there was no padding when I was casting the read bytes to my struct. Simply changing '#pragma pack(1)' to #pragma pack(push,1) before the declaration of my struct and '#pragma pack(pop)' after the declaration brought PCL back to life. Of course that wasn't until recompiling PCL from scratch...lesson learned though!